# tomcat 6 read another directory

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a problem. i have 3 tomcat directories in my windows 8 system :

```
D:/apache tomcat 6/
D:/apache tomcat 6_old/
D:/tomcat6/
```

The last two folders are old and dirty. I want to use fresh first one; so I am trying to run it.

```
D:/apache tomcat 6/bin/tomcat6.exe
```

But strangely windows runs tomcat with configuration and webapps in third one (D:/tomcat6/).
I have set CATALINA_HOME in environment variable; but no effect.

Can you please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you open a command line and try "SET" and look how the CATALINA_HOME directory is set?

Comment: CATALINA_HOME=D:\apache tomcat 6 (it set properly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting CATALINA_HOME helps, but you have to use startup.bat to start Tomcat, not the tomcat6.exe

You can also do this with a small batch file (I use it that way since I have a lot of tomcat installations on my computer. Here is one of my scripts:

```
setlocal
cd C:\mock\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\bin
set CATALINA_HOME=C:\mock\apache-tomcat-7.0.27
call startup.bat
```

Comment: Hi, i use startup.bat it works well. thanks. i just wondering why tomcat6.exe didnt start with proper folder.

Comment: I am not sure what the executable does. I guess it is reading some environment stuff and then gets confused with previous installed versions. With those small batch files it is easy to control which tomcat installation to start. Helps me a lot (we are using a different tomcat version in almost every project)

Answer (score 0):

Don't see any reason why starting first tomcat starts a different one.

You can remove unused tomcat directories, so that you just have single Tomcat. Also make sure to kill all java/tomcat processes and then start the required one.

Comment: hi Rai, i killed all tomcat in my task manager. if i rename the third one tomcat wont start at all..

Comment: then better take backup of your project; remove all installation and take a fresh tomcat from http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi

Answer (score 0):

Change your `CATALINA_HOME`

from

```
D:/tomcat6/
```

**to**

```
D:/apache tomcat 6/
```

also make sure the following is added to `path` variable

```
   %CATALINA_HOME%\bin;
```